# How to delete a row from CSV if value from first cell meets a condition?

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a CSV file with times and tasks:

```
0800,take out trash
1000,read a book
1230,have lunch
1300,buy groceries
1600,meet with friends
2000,go to sleep
```

I want to create a script that when ran, it compares current time to the time in the first field. If the time now greater then this field, it should remove the line.

I have no idea where to start and i'm not much of a programmer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Honestly, you'll have to program in one language or another. I realise this isn't a direct answer, but I recommend you choose a programming language. It helps if you know people who already know it well. Try some tutorials, get to grips with it. Then repeat this question in for the language you've started.

Comment: You have `bash` in your tag, so try `AWK`, it's easy. Start with parsing, then with comparing and then with removing. Or you can use normal `bash` too. It's all on you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Appreciate the input!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The obvious flaw (there's no date component) and the naive CVS (non-quoted strings) aside this should be fairly simple:

I modified your file a bit (because of current time):

```
$ cat time.csv 
0400,take out trash
0600,take out trash
0800,take out trash
1000,read a book
1230,have lunch
1300,buy groceries
1600,meet with friends
2000,go to sleep
```

My current time:

```
06:36:49
```

And running the lot:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ "date \"+%H%M\""|getline time} $1>time' time.csv 
0800,take out trash
1000,read a book
1230,have lunch
1300,buy groceries
1600,meet with friends
2000,go to sleep
```

You just need to capture the output and replace the file.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ "date \"+%H%M\""|getline time} $1>time' time.csv  > time.new && mv time.new time.csv
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I had a completely off approach with loops :) This makes more sense!

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk and `strftime`:

```
$ awk -F, 'strftime("%H%M")<$1' file
2359,hack the planet
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

date=$(date +%H%M)

while read line; do
    if [ $(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1) -gt $date ]; then
        echo $line
    fi
done < $1
```

Test:

```
$ cat foo 
10,a
20,b
2010,b
2020,b
2110,b
$ date
Di  5 Feb 2019 20:18:46 CET
$ ./script.sh foo 
2020,b
2110,b
```

But you have to improve the bashscript a bit, to make it more roboust! my code is a "proof of concept"

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on the mix using `date` to set a variable before comparing with `$1` and using the default action would be:

```
awk -F, -v t=$(date '+%H%M') '$1 > t' file
```

**Example**

```
$ echo $(date '+%H%M')
1341

$ awk -F, -v t=$(date '+%H%M') '$1 > t' file
1600,meet with friends
2000,go to sleep
```